# iOS signal generation pattern not expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, signal-processing, core-audio

I would like to generate the tone with wave pattern as below ( last mid point should be at the bottom tough as previous set.)

[image: Expected]

When after chaining the frequency from 44.44Hz to 45.89 Hz, it becomes

[image: Reality]

Even I have  changed the buffer length from 1024 to 960 , it stills shows that the buffer length is still at 1024 . Hence, it causes the problem that some of the remaining tails displays the mid-point tail instead of bottom .

The below is my code

```
OSStatus RenderTone(
                    void *inRefCon,
                    AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
                    const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
                    UInt32                      inBusNumber,
                    UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
                    AudioBufferList             *ioData)

{
    // Fixed amplitude is good enough for our purposes
    const double amplitude =  2.7171;

    // Get the tone parameters out of the view controller
    ToneGeneratorViewController *viewController =
    (ToneGeneratorViewController *)inRefCon;
    double theta = viewController->theta; //992 f0r 44.44 , 959 for 45.89
    double theta_increment = viewController->sampleRate / viewController->frequency;
    int increment = ceil(theta_increment);
    NSLog(@"increment= %i" , increment);
    const int channel = 0;
    Float32 *buffer = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[channel].mData;
    int squareIndex = 0;

for (UInt32 frame = 0; frame < 401; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 401; frame < 419; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  -amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 419; frame < 468; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 468; frame < 487; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  -amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 487; frame < 536; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 536; frame < 555; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  -amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 555; frame < 604; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 604; frame < 622; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  -amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 622; frame < 671; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 671; frame < 690; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  -amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 690; frame < 739; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 739; frame < 757; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  -amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 757; frame < 806; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 806; frame < 825; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  -amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 825; frame < 874; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 874; frame < 892; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  -amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 892; frame < 941; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  amplitude;
}
for (UInt32 frame = 941; frame < increment; frame++)
{
    buffer[frame] =  -amplitude;
}

squareIndex += 1.0;
if(squareIndex >= theta_increment) squareIndex-=theta_increment;
viewController->theta = theta;


void ToneInterruptionListener(void *inClientData, UInt32 inInterruptionState)
{
    ToneGeneratorViewController *viewController =
    (ToneGeneratorViewController *)inClientData;

    [viewController stop];
}

@implementation ToneGeneratorViewController

@synthesize frequencySlider;
@synthesize playButton;
@synthesize frequencyLabel;

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider
{
    frequency = 45.9;
    frequencyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.1f Hz", frequency];
}

- (void)createToneUnit
{
    // Configure the search parameters to find the default playback output unit
    // (called the kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO on iOS but
    // kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput on Mac OS X)
    AudioComponentDescription defaultOutputDescription;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentFlags = 0;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    // Get the default playback output unit
    AudioComponent defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &defaultOutputDescription);
    NSAssert(defaultOutput, @"Can't find default output");

    // Create a new unit based on this that we'll use for output
    OSErr err = AudioComponentInstanceNew(defaultOutput, &toneUnit);
    NSAssert1(toneUnit, @"Error creating unit: %ld", err);

    // Set our tone rendering function on the unit
    AURenderCallbackStruct input;
    input.inputProc = RenderTone;
    input.inputProcRefCon = self;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(toneUnit,
                               kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                               kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                               0,
                               &input,
                               sizeof(input));
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting callback: %ld", err);

    // Set the format to 32 bit, single channel, floating point, linear PCM
    const int four_bytes_per_float = 4;
    const int eight_bits_per_byte = 8;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
    streamFormat.mSampleRate = sampleRate;
    streamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    streamFormat.mFormatFlags =
    kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
    streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = four_bytes_per_float;
    streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = four_bytes_per_float;
    streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = four_bytes_per_float * eight_bits_per_byte;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty (toneUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                0,
                                &streamFormat,
                                sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting stream format: %ld", err);
}

- (IBAction)togglePlay:(UIButton *)selectedButton
{
    if (toneUnit)
    {
        AudioOutputUnitStop(toneUnit);
        AudioUnitUninitialize(toneUnit);
        AudioComponentInstanceDispose(toneUnit);
        toneUnit = nil;

        [selectedButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Play", nil) forState:0];
    }
    else
    {
        [self createToneUnit];

        // Stop changing parameters on the unit
        OSErr err = AudioUnitInitialize(toneUnit);
        NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error initializing unit: %ld", err);

        // Start playback
        err = AudioOutputUnitStart(toneUnit);
        NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error starting unit: %ld", err);

        [selectedButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Stop", nil) forState:0];
    }
}

- (void)stop
{
    if (toneUnit)
    {
        [self togglePlay:playButton];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self sliderChanged:frequencySlider];
    sampleRate = 44100;

    OSStatus result = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, ToneInterruptionListener, self);
    if (result == kAudioSessionNoError)
    {
        UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
        AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
    }
    AudioSessionSetActive(true);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.frequencyLabel = nil;
    self.playButton = nil;
    self.frequencySlider = nil;

    AudioSessionSetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: When you say you have "changed the buffer length from 1024 to 960", is there code to do this somewhere? Or do you actually mean you're now putting 960 values into the buffer because your increment variable now calculates to 960?

Comment: It is because 960 is the approximate value of number of samples taken per hour but it seems showing the default samples taken is 1024 , which confuses me

Comment: And I am not sure where to change the default samples taken changed  from 1024 to 960

Comment: You can't tell Core Audio exactly how many samples to take. (You can give it a preferred value but it may change this e.g. to a power of 2). Core Audio tells you how many samples per channel it wants when it calls RenderTone. That's what the inNumberFrames parameter is.

Comment: So how am i supposed to generate My custom tone with slightly higher frequency? i just the tail to be removed such that frequenxy meets my requirement

Answer (score 3):

When Core Audio calls your RenderTone callback it wants you to provide a particular number of audio frames per buffer. The 'inNumberFrames' parameter tells you what this number is.

(Core Audio does allow some adjustment of the hardware buffer size but this value may be altered to suit Core Audio e.g. by being rounded up to the next power of 2.)

So you can't adjust the callback buffer size to exactly fit one cycle of a waveform you want to generate: Instead you must keep track of where you currently are in the waveform so you can generate as much or as little of it as required, and then continue where you left off in the next callback.

In your example, if inNumberFrames is 1024 then in the first callback you would supply a complete 960 sample cycle AND an additional 64 samples from the next cycle. In the second callback you would provide the remaining 896 samples of your second cycle and 128 samples from the start of your third cycle, and so on.

Comment: It is given that the LCM of 1024 and 960 is 15360. It turns that we have to fill in 16 buffers of 960 and copy to 15 buffers in 1024 default buffer frame. What should I consider to modify the for loop besides making use of modulus ?

Comment: Yes it turns out that 16 cycles of your waveform fit in 15 buffers of 1024 samples. But you can forget about the buffers and just keep track of where in your waveform you are. E.g. you could add a property to your ToneGeneratorViewController that remembers which sample of the waveform (not the buffer) is next, and increment this (modulo 960) as you generate samples.

Comment: inNumberFrames tells you how many samples to produce in the callback, but the value of each sample depends on where in your waveform you have reached, not on where in the CoreAudio buffer you happen to be.

Comment: So i don't understand how the remaining inNUmberFrames (64,128) .... after putting 960 samples to be brought down to the next for loop cycle until it meets 16 times (960X16 = 1024X15) if the end condition of for loop is fixed to be inNumberFrames instead

Comment: It looks like you started from [this example](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html) but then went wrong. Look at the example again: It uses 'frames' for "how far through the buffer am I?" but uses 'theta' for "how far through my waveform am I?". The loop fills the buffer of size inNumberFrames, but _inside_ the loop 'theta' decides what value goes in the buffer. You have started using 'frame' to decide what value goes into the buffer, which is a mistake.

Comment: So what is the way out to handle the remaining buffer samples to be brought down into next cycle for filling in new samples for new waveform?

Comment: If it's a repeating waveform, you just loop back to the beginning of that waveform if you need more samples to fill the buffer (with inNumberFrames).  Also remember where you left off in the waveform after each buffer so you can start there+1 for the next buffer.